# Is there a way to use the same jni-file in 2 different classes of different packages?

Tags: java-native-interface

I have 2 projects which are interlinked . The jni-file that I'm using for one repository is needed in another also.

```
JNIEXPORT
jboolean JNICALL OBJECT_TRACKER_METHOD(haveObject)(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,
                                                   jstring object_id);
```

This funtion is to be used by another class `Java_com_sensennetworks_senanpr_Tracking_ObjectTracker_` also.

Is there a that i can use the same jni-file for both the repositories?

Comment: Few options here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo052 or http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/ or http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest approach is to just define both functions and have them call a common implementation.

The second approach would be a call to [`RegisterNatives`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods) in the `JNI_OnLoad` function of your library. This allows you to bind arbitrary C/C++ functions to specific methods on specific classes.

Finally, you could convince the linker to create a symbol alias from one to the other.